# Is there a way to call a stored procedure with Dapper?

Tags: .net, stored-procedures, orm, dapper

I am very impressed with the results of [Dapper Micro ORM](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) for stackoverflow.com. I am considering it for my new project and but I have one concern about that some times my project requires to have Stored Procedure and I have search a lot on web but not found anything with stored procedure. So is there any way to have Dapper work with a stored procedure?

Please let me know if it is possible otherwise I have to extend it in my way.

Answer (score 411, accepted):

In the simple case you can do:

```
var user = cnn.Query<User>("spGetUser", new {Id = 1}, 
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).First();
```

If you want something more fancy, you can do:

```
 var p = new DynamicParameters();
 p.Add("@a", 11);
 p.Add("@b", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
 p.Add("@c", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

 cnn.Execute("spMagicProc", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure); 

 int b = p.Get<int>("@b");
 int c = p.Get<int>("@c");
```

Additionally you can use exec in a batch, but that is more clunky.

Comment: Parameter with direction of ReturnValue should be defined first, right?

Comment: @Sam Saffron What is the difference between .Output and .ReturnVlaue ?

Comment: Sam, does this allow result sets from SPROCs?

Comment: I got a scenario where I will be taking the query result set and the Output parameter value in a procedure. If I use `cnn.Query<MyType>` how can I get the value of Output parameter of the proc?

Comment: The second (fancy) solution is also helpful for when you need to pass a null value for one or more stored procedure parameters.

Comment: Execute returns `int` type. So if you need to get the SP result, it won't work.

Comment: How can I pass List<T> for table valued parameter in stored procedure?? @Sam Saffron

Answer (score 15):

I think the answer depends on which features of stored procedures you need to use.

Stored procedures returning a result set can be run using `Query`; stored procedures which don't return a result set can be run using `Execute` - in both cases (using `EXEC <procname>`) as the SQL command (plus input parameters as necessary). See the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) for more details.

As of revision [2d128ccdc9a2](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/detail?spec=svn2d128ccdc9a2ea41f34eccb1a470bdc3df9671c0&r=2d128ccdc9a2ea41f34eccb1a470bdc3df9671c0) there doesn't appear to be native support for `OUTPUT` parameters; you could add this, or alternatively construct a more complex `Query` command which declared TSQL variables, executed the SP collecting `OUTPUT` parameters into the local variables and finallyreturned them in a result set:

```
DECLARE @output int

EXEC <some stored proc> @i = @output OUTPUT

SELECT @output AS output1
```

Comment: just added support for output params now, see my latest checkin

Comment: @Sam - that's what I call service!

Answer (score 12):

Here is code for getting value return from Store procedure

Stored procedure:

```
alter proc [dbo].[UserlogincheckMVC]    
@username nvarchar(max),    
@password nvarchar(max)
as    
begin    
    if exists(select Username from Adminlogin where Username =@username and Password=@password)    
        begin        
            return 1  
        end    
    else    
        begin     
            return 0  
        end    
end
```

Code:

```
var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
string pass = EncrytDecry.Encrypt(objUL.Password);
conx.Open();
parameters.Add("@username", objUL.Username);
parameters.Add("@password", pass);
parameters.Add("@RESULT", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
var RS = conx.Execute("UserlogincheckMVC", parameters, null, null, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
int result = parameters.Get<int>("@RESULT");
```

Answer (score 4):

Same from above, bit more detailed

Using .Net Core

Controller

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private string connectionString;
  
    public IDbConnection Connection
    {
        get { return new SqlConnection(connectionString); }
    }

    public TestController()
    {
        connectionString = @"Data Source=OCIUZWORKSPC;Initial Catalog=SocialStoriesDB;Integrated Security=True";
    }

    public JsonResult GetEventCategory(string q)
    {
        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
        {
            var categories = dbConnection.Query<ResultTokenInput>("GetEventCategories", new { keyword = q },
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).FirstOrDefault();

            return Json(categories);
        }
    }

    public class ResultTokenInput
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }            
    }
}
```

Stored Procedure ( parent child relation )

```
create PROCEDURE GetEventCategories
@keyword as nvarchar(100)
AS
    BEGIN

    WITH CTE(Id, Name, IdHierarchy,parentId) AS
    (
      SELECT 
        e.EventCategoryID as Id, cast(e.Title as varchar(max)) as Name,
        cast(cast(e.EventCategoryID as char(5)) as varchar(max)) IdHierarchy,ParentID
      FROM 
        EventCategory e  where e.Title like '%'+@keyword+'%'
     -- WHERE 
      --  parentid = @parentid

      UNION ALL

      SELECT 
        p.EventCategoryID as Id, cast(p.Title + '>>' + c.name as varchar(max)) as Name,
        c.IdHierarchy + cast(p.EventCategoryID as char(5)),p.ParentID
      FROM 
        EventCategory p 
      JOIN  CTE c ON c.Id = p.parentid

        where p.Title like '%'+@keyword+'%'
    )
    SELECT 
      * 
    FROM 
      CTE
    ORDER BY 
      IdHierarchy
```

References in case

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using SocialStoriesCore.Data;
using Dapper;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Comment: Why using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` ? Only using ***Dapper*** in **DAL** ?

Comment: @PreguntonCojoneroCabrón Not necessary, I just pasted everything

Comment: Sample rows for EventCategory  ?

Comment: @ArunPrasadES to PreguntonCojoneroCabrón point, please clean up and remove unnecessary code as it confuses people trying to solve a problem. There are features in Visual Studio and Resharper that do this usages cleanup for you.

Comment: @PreguntonCojoneroCabrón Removed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` as recommended.

Answer (score 4):

With multiple return and multi parameter

```
string ConnectionString = CommonFunctions.GetConnectionString();
using (IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    // single result
    var results = conn.Query(sql: "ProductSearch", 
        param: new { CategoryID = 1, SubCategoryID="", PageNumber=1 }, 
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

    var salarydetails = reader.Read<dynamic>().ToList();

    // multiple result
    var reader = conn.QueryMultiple("ProductSearch", 
        param: new { CategoryID = 1, SubCategoryID = "", PageNumber = 1 }, 
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure); 

    var userdetails = reader.Read<dynamic>().ToList(); // instead of dynamic, you can use your objects
    var salarydetails = reader.Read<dynamic>().ToList();
}

public static string GetConnectionString()
{
    // Put the name the Sqlconnection from WebConfig..
    return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
}
```

Comment: ***ProductSearch*** _sample_? returns 2 cursors ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ExecuteProcedure<T>(this SqlConnection connection,
    string storedProcedure, object parameters = null,
    int commandTimeout = 180) 
    {
        try
        {
            if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Close();
                connection.Open();
            }

            if (parameters != null)
            {
                return connection.Query<T>(storedProcedure, parameters,
                    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout: commandTimeout);
            }
            else
            {
                return connection.Query<T>(storedProcedure,
                    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout: commandTimeout);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            connection.Close();
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

    }
}

var data = db.Connect.ExecuteProcedure<PictureModel>("GetPagePicturesById",
    new
    {
        PageId = pageId,
        LangId = languageId,
        PictureTypeId = pictureTypeId
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for stored procedure with parameters

```
    var procedureName = "ShowCompanyForProvidedEmployeeId";
    var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
    parameters.Add("Id", id, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
    using (var connection = _context.CreateConnection())
    {
        var company = await connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<CompanyModel>
            (procedureName, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        return company;
    }
```