# Dapper-Dot-Net Example Code

Tags: dapper, sample

This is code cut right from the Dapper examples:

```
var p = new DynamicParameters();
p.Add("@a", 11);
p.Add("@b", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
p.Add("@c", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue); 
cnn.Execute("spMagicProc", p, commandType: commandType.StoredProcedure);
int b = p.Get("@b");
int c = p.Get("@c");
```

**Anyone**: In the above code from the example provided, I get an error, "can't resolve .Execute"--referring to `cnn.Execute`. I look at the connection object and there is no method for Execute. Dapper obviously works well, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `cnn` is a `SqlConnection`; you need to have a reference to the SqlConnection assembly and the Dapper.net assembly. What is the surrounding code in your example?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Metro. Here is the code surrounding.  I have references to dapper as well as SqlClient.  The only compile error I get is for ".Execute". (see next post for code)

Comment: using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)){
                try{
                    connection.Open();

                    //from dapper example
                    var p = new DynamicParameters();
                    p.Add("@a", 11);
                    p.Add("@b", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
                    p.Add("@c", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

connection.Execute("MyDamnStoredProc", p, commandType: commandType.StoredProcedure);
  int b = p.Get<int>("@b");
  int c = p.Get<int>("@c");

Comment: Can you post the entire exception? I see 2 things that could be potential issues: 1. commandType.StoredProcedure should be CommandType.StoredProcedure (notice capitalization); 2. Does the stored proc exist in your database?

Comment: I changed capitolization.  Also, that is the stored proc name.  The code and proc is not meant to be production quality--just an fyi for anyone with concerns.  I just want to see Dapper work.  I'm not sure how to show all the code without breaking it up into multiple posts, so here goes.

Comment: using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using SqlMapper;

Comment: public static class Program
{public static string GetOpenConnection(){
ConnectionStringSettingsCollection settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
Console.WriteLine(settings.Count);
if (settings != null){foreach (ConnectionStringSettings cs in settings){
Console.WriteLine(cs.Name);
Console.WriteLine(cs.ProviderName);
Console.WriteLine(cs.GetType());
Console.WriteLine(cs.ConnectionString);
Console.WriteLine("");
return cs.ConnectionString;
}}
Console.WriteLine("Not good.  There was no connection string in the config file.");
return null;}

Comment: public static void Main(){
string connectionString = GetOpenConnection(); //gets a valid connection string
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)){
try{//from dapper example
var p = new DynamicParameters();
p.Add("@a", 11);
p.Add("@b", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
p.Add("@c", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
connection.Open();
connection.Execute("MyDamnStoredProc", p, CommandType.StoredProcedure);
int b = p.Get<int>("@b");
int c = p.Get<int>("@c");}
catch (Exception ex){Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);}}}}

Comment: Sorry for the crap formattinig, but I can only post 500+ characters at a time.

Comment: This is the entire compile exception:
Error 2 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' does not contain a definition for 'Execute' and no extension method 'Execute' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you able to edit your question with all of this? That's quite a bit to decipher...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this should get you fixed up:

```
using( var connection = new SqlConnection( connectionString ) )
{
    try
    {
        var p = new DynamicParameters();
        p.Add( "a", 11 );
        p.Add( "b", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output );
        p.Add( "c", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue );
        connection.Open();
        connection.Execute( "MyDamnStoredProc", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure );
        int b = p.Get<int>( "b" );
        int c = p.Get<int>( "c" );
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( ex.Message );
    }
}
```

**Notes**:

1. the params don't need the @ symbol; dapper will handle that for you.
2. be sure to use named parameters; see the updated connection.Execute method that specifies the `commandType:` parameter. You do this so the optional parameters can be omitted from the method call.

Comment: Metro, thank you for your help.  I am still getting a compile error, Error 1 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' does not contain a definition for 'Execute' and no extension method 'Execute' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).
Does this compile for you?  if so, I must be missing a reference or something.  I'm using VS2010 Pro/sp1 and .NET 4.0 w/all service packs.

Comment: I'm a bit perplexed with this one now. Everything is pointing to Dapper.net not being properly referenced.

Comment: Thanks Metro.  That is at least a great place to start.  I'll post back what I find.  Thanks again for your help.
-Kevin

Comment: Metro, the things you recommended helped, and helped me to realize that a block of important code was missing from dapper (bad copy/paste on my part).  I am able to execute a stored procedure with dynamic parameters, but I don't know how to retrieve the data selected by the procedure.

Comment: Kevin, take a look at this question: [Is there a way to call a stored procedure with dapper dot net?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5962117/9664). If that doesn't help, I would recommend starting a new question on how to retrieve the results of a Sproc using dapper since this question has been answered, re: the error has been resolved.

Answer (score 7):

> "can't resolve .Execute"

That would be cause your extension method is missing, did you `using Dapper;` at the top of your file.

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx#csharp3.0overview_topic3