# Generic way to insert some data into a table

Tags: ado.net

I have always been using nhibernate ORM for inserting data to sql tables from application.
But recently I tried reading on Ado.net and found suggestion to use stored proc instead of 
sqlcommand.executenonQuery().

In that  case, every table insertion will need a different stored proc . A 100 table application will need 100 Stored procs. Is my understanding correct or is there a better way of doing it in a more generic way?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would use an ORM if I have more than 5 different tables to select and/or insert into. Why should you walk 100 miles if the bus stop is right infront of the door?

That said the **ORM** is a generic way to access data. If you would want to code everything by hand, you could surely write stored procedures with optional parameters, but I don't recomend it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I thought I was missing some thing when i read "Use stored procedure for inserting data" and there is some generic stored proc that can be written to do it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple one-liner command can be an INSERT given directly in .NET code via parameterized Command class. Something like:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
        using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable (Field1, Field2) VALUES (@Param1, @Param2)", sqlConn)) {
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", someValue1);  
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param2", someValue2); 
            sqlConn.Open();  
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
        }  
    }
```

So it doesn't have to be a stored proc for every command. You can have a class or classes dedicated to DB access only (db access layer) and populate it with various methods to read/write from DB. You can even have a generic method that automatically derives parameters for INSERT/UPDATE commands.

Of course if it's more than 1-2 commands or some logic is involved - that asks for a stored procedure.

Btw, this is my personal opinion, but i think ORMs are evil.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard about [dapper](/questions/tagged/dapper), a powerful tool to ***execute a query and map the results to a strongly typed List***.  Dapper also support ***stored procedures***, check [this](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) out.

**Example:**

```
dbConnection.Query<return type>("yourSP", parameters, 
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).First();
```

Also take some time to check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962117/is-there-a-way-to-call-a-stored-procedure-with-dapper).