# Best way to get data from Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, datatable

For years, I've been using the DataTable object to get data out of my stored procs.

Nothing wrong with it, but is there a fancier object for that now ?

Comment: Linq to SQL or Entity Data Model can be used and are a lot easier to control than data tables.

Comment: LINQ and Entity Framework are the flavors of the month but it depends what version of .NET you are using.

Comment: See if you can define a relationship for a view in EF's XML editor without pulling your hair out.

Comment: I often find EF overkill - we use Linq to SQL in preference 99% of the time, is much neater IMO.

Comment: "Nothing wrong with it" - there I'm afraid I must disagree with you, and I fully support your decision to try other things. And for my next predictable rant: "why stored procedures are over-rated and usually both unnecessary and actively unhelpful" :p

Answer (score 2):

Try Dapper, the MicroORM that powers stackoverflow too. 
Dapper is blazing fast and not a one-size-fits-all ORM like Entity Framework. If you are good with SQL, then this is the way to go.

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5971847/325521) that Dapper creator [Sam Saffron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17174/sam-saffron) has posted, showing how to use Dapper to execute Stored Procedures.