# Error could not find stored procedure with Dapper and c# only when I specify commandType

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm using Dapper with C# and SQL Server. I have an stored procedure in SQL Server that inserts a person into my database. The problem is that when I specify in the query that its an stored procedure I get

> Could not find stored procedure

but without using `commandType`, everything works fine.

For example: I had the following code:

```
var result = connection.Execute("KBunnyGame_Players_InsertPlayer @Name, @Score, @FacebookId", player, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

And I kept getting the error, but after I changed to:

```
var result = connection.Execute("KBunnyGame_Players_InsertPlayer @Name, @Score, @FacebookId", player);
```

I didn't get the error anymore and the player got inserted in the database.
I don't know if that's the expected behaviour, it seems weird to me. Is there any documentation I could follow?

**EDIT:**

Stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[KBunnyGame_Players_InsertPlayer] 
    @Name NCHAR(20),
    @Score INT,
    @FacebookId NCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO KBunnyGame_Players (name, score, facebookId) 
    VALUES (@Name, @Score, @FacebookId); 
END
```

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for the suggestion, already done

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/25592031 help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't specify the parameters in the command-text when using `CommandType.StoredProcedure`; provide **just** the name - the parameters are passed by name already.

If you need to filter the properties on the object, use a projection:

```
var result = connection.Execute("KBunnyGame_Players_InsertPlayer",
    new { player.Name, player.Score, player.FacebookId },
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

SQL Server has implicit `EXEC` if something looks sufficiently close enough to an `EXEC`, which is why the other version works. So if you prefer: use that. With or without a leading `EXEC`.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. Just a small question, is there any difference between 
specifying the commandType.StoredProcedure, and using it without it?, or is it the same either way?

Comment: @Teler ADO.NET (and more specifically: SqlClient) treats the two scenarios very differently. With just the name and with `CommandType.Text` (or omitted) you wouldn't actually be passing the parameters - you'd be invoking it with the default parameters