# Call Stored procedure in aspcore than return custom message

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, odata

If someone can help me here , i would like to call a stored procedure in a post odata request but this procedure only return a custom message ...
Is it possible or not at all ?

Comment: take a look on this example using Dapper https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962117/is-there-a-way-to-call-a-stored-procedure-with-dapper

Comment: but i'm using entity ....

Comment: Is it right to combine entity with dappler ?

Comment: And odata need a Queryable output ...

Comment: With entity framework also you can follow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599404/how-to-run-stored-procedures-in-entity-framework-core