# Dapper Not able to parse column String

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, dapper

I have the following table

```
create table tblWorkers
(
    Id int identity,
    WorkerId nvarchar(8),

    Username NVARCHAR(50) not null,
    Password NVARCHAR(12) not null,
    Token NVARCHAR(max) null,
    CONSTRAINT PK_WorkerId PRIMARY KEY (WorkerId)
)
```

When I try the following Dapper code, by passing 
Username:W01, Password=check123
I get an error, Error parsing column 0 (UserId=W01 - String)'.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

``

```
        DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        parameters.Add("@userName", loginModel.Username, DbType.String);
        parameters.Add("@password", loginModel.Password, DbType.String);
        using (IDbConnection con = _connectionManager.GetConnection())
        {
            con.Open();
            var result = con.Query<User>(StoredProcedures.uspAuthenticate, param: parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            return result.FirstOrDefault();
```

``
StoredProcedure is as below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspAuthenticate] 
    @userName nvarchar(8),
    @password nvarchar(12)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select WorkerId
    from tblWorkers
    where Username = @username and Password = @password
END
```

Please advise.

Comment: This is not a real-world production app where you're storing passwords in plain text, right?

Comment: Please Include the error stacktrace.

Comment: @squillman No its not

Comment: You can check the examples in the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962117/is-there-a-way-to-call-a-stored-procedure-with-dapper

Comment: Please include the definition of your `User` class. It's probably an error deserializing `User.UserId` from the response.

Comment: The error says mentions it has a problem parsing UserId, but your stored procedure only returns WorkerId.  You need to post your User class.  Also, you have Username defined as both nvarchar(50) and nvarchar(8).  Pick one.

Comment: Also, if WorkerId is a natural primary key, then you probably should not have Id in your tblWorkers table, and should just remove that column unless there is a compelling reason (HIPAA, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dapper expects SQL and .NET to be the same.  The error mentions UserId, code examples show parameter as username (not id).

you say 'when passing: Username:W01'
The error shows 'Error parsing column 0 (UserId=W01 - String)'

Answer (score 1):

Also check the type.  I do not think the case needs to match but the type does.  In my case the class field was int but SQL was returning varchar2.